# SELECT 'description' from table based on a specific condition

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables:

table1

```
**column0**       **description**
foo               this
bar               that
hello             yellow
bye               sky
...
baz               fred
```

table2

```
**column1**       **column2**
foo
bar               hello
...
baz               bye
```

Column0 has everything in column1 and column2

I want to select the description from table 1 based on the following conditions:

1) If column2 is empty, then select the description where column1 = column0.

2) Else, display the description where column2 = column0

Please let me know if any clarification is needed. I am trying to do this in postgresql.

****************UPDATE****************:

The result based on the information you can see from the tables would be

1. the description for 'foo' which is 'this' as column2 is empty next to 'foo'
2. the description for 'hello' as this is not empty in column2
3. the description for 'bye' as this is not empty in column2

Hence:

```
this

yellow

sky
```

Comment: (1) What results do you want?  (2) What database are you using?  I removed the incompatible database tags.  (3) You say "Column0 has everything in column1 and column2", but the sample data provides no evidence of that.

Comment: Gordon Linoff - the sample data did not provide any evidence of that which is precisely why I stated that it did. I have edited this now just for you.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: Will - As far as my SQL skills go, I could only come up with this (it only gets the description for column1) SELECT table1.description FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column0 = table2.column1

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the tables and use `COALESCE()`in the `ON` clause like this:

```
select t1.description
from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1
on coalesce(t2.column2, t2.column1) = t1.column0
```

You may also need an `ORDER BY` clause to get the results in the order that you want.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5hinRU9ac9U4BHxMCdrfsK/0).
Results:

```
| description |
| ----------- |
| sky         |
| this        |
| yellow      |
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? Wrong results?

Comment: Did you check the demo? It works for the sample data and the logic that you provided.

Comment: No errors - just the wrong results. You are correct, I do need an ORDER BY though I don't know how to use this.

Comment: Why wrong results? You can see in the demo that the results are correct.

Comment: There is no order in a table. You define the order by using an ORDER BY clause. Do you have a column to sort the results? If you do use it. If not then there is no order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select test from(
select case when t2.column2 is null then t1.description
            else null
      end test
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t1.column0 = t2.column1) A
where test is not null;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b4770ec2b271f4c2e308b7e2d2348d73)

Comment: I tried this but it is missing some descriptions for the second column

Comment: What do you mean by this " it is missing some descriptions for the second column"?

Answer (score 0):

I think `exists` might be sufficient:

```
select t1.description
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t2.column1 = t1.column0
             ) or
      exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t2.column2 = t1.column0
             );
```

That said, your specific rules appear to be:

```
select t1.description
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.column1 = t1.column0 and
        t2.column2 is null left join
     table2 tt2
     on tt2.column2 = t1.column0 and
        t2.column1 is null
where t2.column1 is not null or
      tt2.column2 is not null;
```